# Merge [photography] and [astrophotography]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, merge-request

We have two very similar tags on the site: [photography](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/photography) and [astrophotography](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/astrophotography). According to the excerpts, the first one is for

> Questions about photography of celest[r]ial objects by amateur astronomers.

and the second one for

> Questions related to techniques and equipment related to amateur to professional astronomical photography.

Neither of them has a tag wiki. There aren't many professional (astro)photography questions for the second tag either, so can a ♦ moderator merge them, please? Since 'astro' is already in our site name, I'd prefer to keep the [photography](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/photography) tag as the main one. I've [suggested an edit](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/13778) to the excerpt to provide some usage guidance:

> Questions about photography of celestial objects by amateur or professional astronomers. Questions about photography of other objects are off-topic but might be asked on our sister site Photography Stack Exchange.

Comment: I've merged [tag:astrophotography] >> [tag:photography].